# c# passing multiple lists to FormUrlEncodedContent

Tags: c#

I am performing a HTTP requests and I would like to pass multiple items to my post request.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SubmitInspection(
                List<NewsModel> newitems, List<ChildrenModel> childs)
{

    //how do i add the above lists to one item to pass to the http body
    var values =  //stuck here = newitems and childs lists

    var body= new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = await http.PostAsync(url, body);
    return response;
}
```

How do I add both List items(passed as parameters in the method above) to my HTTP body?

Comment: `var values = new { NewItems = newItems, Childs = childs };` you can use anonymous type for that, or maybe you're trying to do something else.

Comment: What about in the case when i have some different types eg: Lists and strings

Comment: You can create [`Anonymous type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) dynamically. So, you can pass strings, arrays, lists or whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks @Givi also anonymous types works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply declare an array and initialize the `FormUrlEncodedContent` with it:

```
   var values =  new[] { newitems, childs}
   var body= new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
```

Comment: This works but what about the case when i have strings and Lists

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on data like this as well.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SubmitInspection(List<object> newitems, List<object> childs)
    {
        //how do i add the above lists to one item to pass to the http body
        //stuck here = newitems and childs lists
        var myContent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { newitems, childs });
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var response = await new HttpClient().PostAsync("", byteContent);
        return response;
    }
```